# How to redirect Homepage to another page when user login

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect

I have a wordpress that users can register and become a member, and how do I get my homepage https://sample.com redirected to the settings page https://sample.com/setting for example. so when the user login, they cannot access the homepage which is https://sample.com

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin solution or a code solution? If you have code, can you share it here?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of variations. One can use [`wp_safe_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) or [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).

If the home page is your front page, something like this would do the work:

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page()) {
            wp_safe_redirect('https://sample.com/dash'); # Using wp_safe_redirect
            exit; 
        }
    }
}
```

If you know the ID of the page (to check how does one see the ID of the page, see note below), one could use something like

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(765)) {
        wp_redirect('https://sample.com/dash'); # Using wp_redirect
        exit;
    }
}
```

Or

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in())) {
        if (is_page(765)){ # If the user is in the page with the ID 765
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink('234')); # To get the URL of a specific page from the ID, and using wp_redirect
            exit; 
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** In order to check the ID of a page, access the Pages section in the WP Admin Dashboard and scroll on top of the page. See image below [(Source)](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-find-post-category-tag-comments-or-user-id-in-wordpress/)

[image]

Alternatively, if one access the page or post, one should also be able to see the page ID on the URL. See image below [(Source)](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-find-post-category-tag-comments-or-user-id-in-wordpress/)

[image]